# Vertical Alignment of text in Titleps

Tags: header-footer, titleps

I am trying to create a header with titleps for my document with an image on left and text on center. I was able to successfully put the image on the left.

Here is what I do:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{graphicx, array}
\usepackage[margin=1in, headheight=102, columnsep=.8cm, top=4.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titleps}
\usepackage{lipsum} %

\newpagestyle{myheader}{%
    \sethead{\includegraphics[width=1.98cm,height=1.69cm]{universe}}{Lorem ipsum}
    \headrule
}
\pagestyle{myheader}

\begin{document}

\section{Section One}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Subsection One}
\lipsum[2]
\subsection{Subsection Two}
\lipsum[3]
\subsection{Subsection Three}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

And here is what I get, with text aligned on bottom:

[image: output]

How can I center this text vertically?

Here is universe.jpg to be able to compile the code[image: universe]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code snippet compilable to help us help you (e.g. fix the error concerning missing units).

Comment: @TeXnician I added the missing picture. Also a link where people can edit the document: https://www.overleaf.com/8296782261cvkftpgmdskd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This  seems to do what you want:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{graphicx, array}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} 
\usepackage[margin=1in, headheight=102pt, columnsep=.8cm, top=4.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titleps}
\usepackage{lipsum} %

\newpagestyle{myheader}{%
    \sethead{\includegraphics[width=1.98cm,height=1.69cm, valign=c]{universe}}{Lorem ipsum}
    \headrule
}
\pagestyle{myheader}

\begin{document}

\section{Section One}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Subsection One}
\lipsum[2]
\subsection{Subsection Two}
\lipsum[3]
\subsection{Subsection Three}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]